# Conditioning a CTMC on the future on a Yule pure birth process

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I need to solve a problem where I am asked to calculate $M=P(X(0)=2|X(1)=3,X(2)=4,X(3)=5)$ in a Yule pure birth process where $\lambda=1$, so $\lambda_n=\lambda.n=n$ and $\mu_i=0$ (the death rate is 0) for a CTMC: Continuous Time Markov Chain.

The first thing that comes to mind is to reformulate the problem using $P(B|A)=P(A,B)/P(A)$ where making:

$A:\{X(1)=3,X(2)=4,X(3)=5\}$
$B:\{X(0)=2\}$

I get:

$M=\frac{P(X(0)=2,X(1)=3,X(2)=4,X(3)=5)}{P(X(1)=3,X(2)=4,X(3)=5)}$

and decomposing the terms and using the markovian property:
$M=\frac{P(X(3)=5|X(2)=4)P(X(2)=4|X(1)=3)P(X(1)=3|X(0)=2)}{P(X(3)=5|X(2)=4)P(X(2)=4|X(1)=3)}=P(X(1)=3|X(0)=2)$

However this doesn't seem right to me, and I don't know where I'm making the mistake. Suppose I solve the problem using Bayes rule: $P(A|B)P(B)=P(B|A)P(A)$

then $M=\frac{P(X(1)=3,X(2)=4,X(3)=5|X(0)=2)}{P(X(1)=3,X(2)=4,X(3)=5)}P(X(0)=2)$,

Here I can simplify the numerator and denominator again and get in the most reduced form:

$M=P(X(1)=3|X(0)=2)P(X(0)=2)$.

As you can see the P(X(0)=2) term popped up which is new. This answer makes more sense to me, but the problem is how am I supposed to calculate P(X(0)=2)? I'm assuming I can get it by computing the stationary distribution with $\pi.G=0$, and get $\pi_j=\pi_2$. However given that $\pi_j \rightarrow P_{ij}(t)$, when $t \rightarrow \infty$; $P_{ij}(t)\rightarrow 0$, given that $P_{ij}(t)=\binom{j-1}{i-1}e^{-i\lambda t}(1-e^{-\lambda t})^{j-1}, j\geq i$.

I can't seem to find the mistake, my math says that the M should be zero, but my intuition suspects that this isn't the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a strange question, because usually in a CTMC the value at $t=0$ is specified.
The transition rates don't determine the probabilities by themselves, you have
to say how the process starts out.
You could get the result in terms of the probabilities $P(X(0)=n)$: I get
$$ P(X(0)=2 | X(1)=3, X(2)=4, X(3) = 5) = \dfrac{P(X(0)=2) P_{23}(1)}{P(X(0)=0) P_{03}(1) + P(X(0)=1) P_{13}(1) + P(X(0)=2) P_{23}(1) + P(X(0)=3) P_{33}(1)}$$

You are correct that for a pure birth process with $\lambda$ bounded below, there is no stationary distribution: the population just keeps increasing indefinitely.

Comment: The exact wording for the problem is: "Find the probability that the initial population is $X(0)=2$, and we have $X(1)=3, X(2)=4, X(3)=5$." I'm assuming this is the same as P(X(0)=2|X(1)=3,X(2)=4,X(3)=5). Perhaps there's a way to condition on $X(1)$, and arrive to the answer?

Comment: "and", not "given that".  I suspect that they really meant to say "Given that the initial population is $X(0)=2$, find the probability that $X(1)=3,X(2)=4,X(3)=5$".  Best to ask your instructor for clarification.

Comment: Yes, I just asked my instructor today. What they really are asking for is: $P(X(1)=3,X(2)=4,X(3)=5|X(0)=2)$! My mistake, and thanks for your clarification!